# Updating to latest Swift version problems

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, xcode8.2, swift3

I just updated to the latest version of Swift and I am getting issues with a breakpoint error. There are no errors in the console.

```
backgroundsetting.innerColor = UIColor.rgb(fromHex: 0xB0E7D7)

backgroundsetting.outterColor = UIColor.rgb(fromHex: 0x005E7D)

backgroundsetting.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width * 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)) 
self.view.addSubview(backgroundsetting)
```

Then after the update it wanted me to set the `backgroundsetting.frame as! CGRect` and it crashes the app when I open that part of the app. Why is this occurring? Here is the after code:

```
backgroundsetting.innerColor = UIColor.rgb(fromHex: 0xB0E7D7)

backgroundsetting.outterColor = UIColor.rgb(fromHex: 0x005E7D)

backgroundsetting.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width * 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)) as! CGRect
self.view.addSubview(backgroundsetting)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `backgroundsetting.frame` property is a type of `CGRect`, why not creating a `CGRect` like this:

```
backgroundsetting.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width * 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: genius anything times 0 equals zero. why not `backgroundsetting.frame = view.frame` ?

Comment: Of course it equals zero; it's a fail-safe; just in-case any future device that apple releases is of different characteristics

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraint for your view and then use height:self.view.frame.size.height and width:self.view.frame.size.width , it will not show proper height and width as compare to your iPhone screen.

For that its better to use UIScreen size i.e      UIScreen.main.bounds.height and UIScreen.main.bounds.width , it will always show original width and height of your iPhone.

```
    backgroundsetting.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width * 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) as! CGRect
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundsetting)
```